# Python Requests (2.27.1) and Request URL Modifications During Pagination Loop

Tags: python, python-requests

So I am working on a Python SDK for an API my company offers to clients. There are a number of requests which are paginated and I have historically been able to perform the pagination without issue.

Just today though (not sure if something changed in my dev environment, package version changes, etc.) I am seeing this strange behavior with the `requests` module.

In my class I create a class variable for a `requests` session that sets a content type and authorization header. Pretty basic.

Then I make a `get` call with a URL. Note that the below example is generic in nature and can take other methods but I am using `get` for this.

`response = self.session.request(method, url, params=params, data=data, json=json)`

I can then pull the required data and pagination items from the response and iterate until all pages are completed.

However when I try this now the `url` is continually being modified by having the `params` appended to the end as part of the query string. So I get this kind of behavior for the URL now.

```
https://example.com/api/apps/abc/environments/def/permissions
https://example.com/api/apps/abc/environments/def/permissions?page=0&size=100
https://example.com/api/apps/abc/environments/def/permissions?page=0&size=100&page=1&size=100
https://example.com/api/apps/abc/environments/def/permissions?page=0&size=100&page=1&size=100&page=1&size=100
https://example.com/api/apps/abc/environments/def/permissions?page=0&size=100&page=1&size=100&page=1&size=100&page=1&size=100
https://example.com/api/apps/abc/environments/def/permissions?page=0&size=100&page=1&size=100&page=1&size=100&page=1&size=100&page=1&size=100
```

As you can see the URL keeps getting the `params` dict appended to the end of it. It never makes it past page `1` since the server is taking the first parameter it finds in the duplicated list of parameters. It IS possible that the server behavior has changed and is now taking the first instead of the last, but I have not yet been able to confirm that.

Is this type of behavior expected? I can do a `url = url.split('?')[0]` to get back to the original `url` and everything works as expected.

Any help or insight would be appreciated.

EDIT: below is the pagination loop. Other methods in the class like `get`, `post`, etc. will call this `__requests` method.

I am seeing the issue when `pagination_type` is `inline`. The rest of the `if` statement is not used here.

```
import json as native_json

def __request(self, method, url, params=None, data=None, json=None):
    return_data = []
    num_iterations = 1
    pagination_type = None
    while True:  # infinite loop in case of pagination - we will break the loop when needed
        response = self.session.request(method, url, params=params, data=data, json=json)
        self.__check_response_for_error(response)   # handle an error response
        if self.__response_has_no_content(response):  # handle no content responses
            return None

        # load the result as a dict
        try:
            result = response.json()
        except native_json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:  # if we cannot decode json then the response isn't json
            return response.content.decode('utf-8')

        # check on the pagination and iterate if required - we only need to check on this after the first
        # request - checking it each time can screw up the logic when dealing with pagination coming from
        # the response headers as the header won't exist which will mean pagination_type will change to 'none'
        # which means we drop into the else block below and assign just the LAST page as the result, which
        # is obviously not what we want to be doing.
        if num_iterations == 1:
            pagination_type = self.__pagination_type(response.headers, result)

        if pagination_type == 'inline':
            return_data += result['data']
            count = result['count']
            page = result['page']
            size = result['size']
            if size * (page + 1) >= count:  # if we have reached the max number of records time to break the loop
                break
            else:  # else loop again after incrementing the page number by 1
                params['page'] = page + 1
        elif pagination_type == 'audit':
            # do stuff not relevant to this question
        elif pagination_type == 'report':
            # do stuff not relevant to this question
        elif pagination_type == 'secmgr':
            # do stuff not relevant to this question
        else:  # we are not dealing with pagination so just return the response as-is
            return_data = result
            break

        num_iterations += 1

    # finally return the response data
    return return_data
```

EDIT 2: The below code works fine/as expected so I am clearly messing something up. Just can't pinpoint it yet.

```
def main():
    session = requests.session()
    params = {
        'page': 1
    }
    url = 'https://httpbin.org/get'

    for x in range(10):
        print(f'url before request: {url}')
        print(params)
        response = session.request('get', url,  params=params)
        print(f'url after request: {response.request.url}')
        params['page'] = params['page'] + 1
        print('*' * 60)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

With output...

```
url before request: https://httpbin.org/get
{'page': 1}
url after request: https://httpbin.org/get?page=1
************************************************************
url before request: https://httpbin.org/get
{'page': 2}
url after request: https://httpbin.org/get?page=2
************************************************************
url before request: https://httpbin.org/get
{'page': 3}
url after request: https://httpbin.org/get?page=3
************************************************************
url before request: https://httpbin.org/get
{'page': 4}
url after request: https://httpbin.org/get?page=4
************************************************************
url before request: https://httpbin.org/get
{'page': 5}
url after request: https://httpbin.org/get?page=5
************************************************************
url before request: https://httpbin.org/get
{'page': 6}
url after request: https://httpbin.org/get?page=6
************************************************************
url before request: https://httpbin.org/get
{'page': 7}
url after request: https://httpbin.org/get?page=7
************************************************************
url before request: https://httpbin.org/get
{'page': 8}
url after request: https://httpbin.org/get?page=8
************************************************************
url before request: https://httpbin.org/get
{'page': 9}
url after request: https://httpbin.org/get?page=9
************************************************************
url before request: https://httpbin.org/get
{'page': 10}
url after request: https://httpbin.org/get?page=10
************************************************************
```

Comment: `requests` cannot change your `url` variable.  That's just not how Python works.  Are you, perhaps, fetching the URL from the session object and overwriting your variable?

Comment: Could you share the **Pagination Loop** you have mentioned in the title?

Comment: @ArtyomVancyan I have added the loop code. Thanks for reviewing!.

Comment: @TimRoberts I don't *think* I am grabbing the `url` from the session object.

Comment: @thomas, there is no reuse of `url`, so this code is clear. You should look for the issue where the `__request` is called.

Comment: @ArtyomVancyan thanks. I was just about to go upstream to see what I can find.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, finally. As @TimRoberts suspected the URL was in fact getting overwritten with `response.request.url` elsewhere in the code. That issue has been fixed and everything is working fine now.